# What is correct usage of [military-sf]?

Tags: discussion, tags

> Military science fiction is a sub-genre of science fiction for which the principal characters are members of a military service and an armed conflict is occurring, often in space or on a planet other than Earth [excerpted from Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Military_scifi).
>
> - <sub>tag wiki excerpt</sub>

However, these questions [(1)](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/119643/how-is-the-republic-military-divided) [(2)](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/119561/why-did-the-empire-not-put-their-stormtroopers-in-camouflage-when-they-were-stat) [(3)](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/119538/jedi-naval-ranks) [(4)](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/117325/what-is-the-rank-structure-of-stormtroopers) (there are more, just not looking now) are using this tag for questions about an army. Should this be [warfare](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/warfare)? **Update**: They now no longer have this tag. Thanks @rand al'thor ♦!

And if so, what should [military-sf](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/military-sf) be used for?

Comment: Update: the 4 questions you linked to no longer have the [tag:military-sf] tag.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The tag should only be used to ask  questions about the subgenre.

Someone following it searching on that tag would not immediately be able to answer a question on Jedi commanders,  but could more  easily answer how Jedi being defacto commanders related to common themes in military sci-fi.

Comment: +1. In the same way that [tag:fantasy-genre] and [tag:science-fiction-genre] are only to be used for questions about the genre, not for questions about any book which happens to be in that genre.

Answer (score 7):

Military science fiction is a sub-genre, so the tag would apply to any work that is arguably military science fiction, especially if discussing a military aspect of the story.

It would not apply to a work just because it has military elements in it.

While most people would not consider Star Wars to be milSF, it could certainly be argued since large parts of the total story universe revolve around characters who are, or end up in, the military and much of the action is preparing for, or engaging in, combat.

Answer (score 6):

Another use, as with every genre tag, would be on [story-identification](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/story-identification) questions.